# ASP.NET MVC - ref is null when user goes from youtube.com

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, youtube

I develop an ASP.NET MVC application and I need to get url of youtube page, from user goes to my page. For example, on youtube.com under my video I put a link to my web-site. When user goes to my website I should receive link to youtube page. I try to receive this link using the next code:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

but when I go to my page from youtube.com the Request.UrlReferrer is null.

Also, note, that I click on my link on youtube.com page I go to my page thru page like:

https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=http%3A%2F%2mysite.azurewebsites.net%2FHome%2FFillForm%3FFormID%3DbdHN7K9oFkQ&redir_token=tl-svjka0c6n2TVko3CXXXoDak18MTM5NzMyODMwMUAxMzk3MjQxOTAx

How can I get UrlReferrer value?

Comment: what you can do is append some query string with your website and track that... because youtube make a new redirect request you won't get things in urlreferrer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the fact that it's redirecting from an `https` URL to an `http` URL and the browser gets paranoid about security.

That said, the referer header is not guaranteed to be sent in any case and your logic can't depend on it being available.